# Is it possible to use EdgeCapacity in FindMinimumCostFlow?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm having trouble getting the EdgeCapacity feature in FindMinimumCostFlow to work.  I have attached a simple example.  We have a simple graph of four vertices.  There are two paths from the "source" to the "sink."  The EdgeCapacity of all edges is limited to 1 and the total flow from the "source" to the "sink" is 2.

```
myGraph = Graph[
  {Property[
    "source" \[DirectedEdge] "vA", {EdgeCapacity -> 1, EdgeCost -> 2}],
   Property[
    "vA" \[DirectedEdge] "sink", {EdgeCapacity -> 1, EdgeCost -> 2}],
   Property[
    "source" \[DirectedEdge] "vB", {EdgeCapacity -> 1, EdgeCost -> 1}],
   Property[
    "vB" \[DirectedEdge] "sink", {EdgeCapacity -> 1, EdgeCost -> 1}]}];


sourceSink = 
 ReplaceAll[#, {"source" -> 2, "sink" -> -2, "vA" -> 0, "vB" -> 0}] &@
  VertexList@myGraph;

flow = FindMinimumCostFlow[myGraph, sourceSink, "OptimumFlowData"];

MatrixForm@flow["FlowMatrix"]
  {{0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0}}
```

The result is not what I expected.  Since the capacity of each path is 1, I would expect the flow to be evenly split.  Instead, it appears to ignore the EdgeCapacity and route all the flow through the path of least resistance.

Comment: FindMinimumCostFlow finds *A* flow of minimum total cost from a set of supply vertices to a set of demand vertices in a graph with capacity constraints and edge costs--not necessarily *ALL* flows.  To do that I suggest you either write full search code, or find ONE flow, alter a unique link in it, then search again, and check whether the second flow has the same value.  If so, iterate.

Comment: Thanks David.  That did in fact work well for me.  On each iteration, I (1) noted the used paths, (2) appropriately reduced the expected flow from the sources and sinks by the capacity of these paths and (3) added a substantial cost to reusing these paths.  I then iterated with the new network.

However, the question remains, does FindMinimumCostFlow honor capacities at all?